# CDN for zocial css file

Tags: cdn, css3

I am looking to use zocial css file for a site and need to figure out if any CDN hosts this file.  If not, I will resort to using the local server (or my own CDN package).  I do not think relying on github for this file is the right approach (in the absence of any CDN).  I will be happy if anyone else thinks otherwise and shares their thoughts.  Thank you!

Comment: Not to be rude or anything but why don't you host this file yourself? its under 100kb and that would not even be more than £0.12p a month. In fact it would be beneficial to move all the template files including JS to a CDN and have them host it while trying to find a free solution. It's as little as 0.12p a GB storage and send on most CDN's its pennies! and much cheaper than webhosting. Just my 2 cents, why spend time searching for something when you simply host it on your OWN CDN.

Comment: the question was not centered around COST but to figure out if an existing CDN actually does host the file or not.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts on hosting on a CDN.

Comment: I'm fully aware of your question and hence I did not answer it using the answer button. The comment was used to give feedback. Your better of with one CDN than multiples due to the fact this will increase look up time. I'm already guessing if your looking for free CDN's then you already have 1-2 in your inventory already.

Comment: You can request it's added to cdnjs at https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs